# A database error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a procedure but having some problem in it. It shows an `error 1458` and *syntax error* please help. Below is my procedure

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ABC`.`` ()$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `ABC`.`` ()
    BEGIN
    After insert on table1 for each row
    INSERT INTO table2
    set student_id = student_id  ,
    Name= Name  ,
    Marks_1=Marks_1,
    Marks_2=Marks_2,
    total=total,
    couter= counter mod student_id  ;

    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Above code shows an error *1458* ... been said to try to fix from out what can be done

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share the exact error please?

Comment: A couple of details, 1. what is the name of the stored procedure? `` Is not a valid name. 2. Internally it has a kind of definition of trigger, do you want to create a trigger within the stored procedure?